# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when running Appium Test

Tags: eclipse, selenium, appium

I'm getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError on my appium tests. The same tests have been running but left for a while and not running anymore . I have tried several things but no solution

ERROR
AILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod setUp1
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
`com.google.common.base.Throwables.throwIfUnchecked(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V

`
POM.XML

java-client
7.3.0

guava
23.0<

selenium-java
3.141.59